# Each cell in a dataframe contains a list of values - how do I select the first value?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have a dataframe and I want to select the first value in the list of each cell.

I have tried:

```
for i in clean_columns:
    print(clean_columns[i][:][0][0])
```

But it selects only the first row. How do I select the first value from every row so I'm left with a dataframe minus the values in parenthesis. Thanks

Comment: Since your data is > 2 dimensions, your should probably consider using numpy directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```

or, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html?highlight=stack#pandas.DataFrame.stack), use [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) locator, [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html?highlight=unstack#pandas.Series.unstack):

```
df.stack().str[0].unstack()
```

or, [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html):

```
df.apply(lambda c: c.str[0])
```

Example:

```
# input
df = pd.DataFrame([[[0, 1] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)])
#         0       1       2
# 0  [0, 1]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
# 1  [0, 1]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
# 2  [0, 1]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]

# output
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
```

Comment: `df.apply(lambda c: c.str[0])` worked a treat, thank you!

Comment: @cloudycider note that the `applymap` version will trigger an error if there is one item that is not iterable while the others will return NaN

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are always the same length, you can use numpy to slice the element you want, then reconstruct the DataFrame. Might be faster since it avoids explicit looping.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[list('abcde') for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(3)],
                  columns=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April'])
#               Jan              Feb              Mar            April
#0  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]
#1  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]
#2  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]  [a, b, c, d, e]   


Nelem = 0  # Element in the list you want
pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.to_numpy().tolist(), dtype='object')[:, :, Nelem],
             index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
  Jan Feb Mar April
0   a   a   a     a
1   a   a   a     a
2   a   a   a     a
```

​